# Flutter - flutter_blue is there a way to call read/write when the characteristics known

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to implement a flutter code that will control NIR Spectrometer via BLE.
I have a very long protocol of service and characteristic uuid pair, and I actually did the same in ionic by just using the uuid pairs and it worked fine...
Is there a way in flutter to call read/write/notify with out do all the:

```
    List<BluetoothService> services = await device.discoverServices();
  services.forEach((service) {
    // do something with service
    for(BluetoothCharacteristic c in characteristics) {
        // save the characteristic for latter usage if needed
    }
});
```

something like:

```
c = BluetoothCharacteristic(device, service_uuid, characteristic_uuid); // why there is no constructor!!
```

It's going to make life more easy for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally gave up, also some services that I need don't do advertisement.. So I started to use the plugin [flutter_reactive_ble](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_reactive_ble) which gives me this option